# System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. When entering a value in a text box

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a simple program that will allow you to enter a degree and have a dial fill to that exact degree, and then also display the degree inside of the dial. The project builds without errors, and will display correctly until a value is entered into the textbox, and then I will get the error on the line

```
 g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
```

If I comment out that line it will go down to the line below it. This is my first time using vb.net, so I'm guessing there is something small I'm just doing incorrectly. My full code is:

```
 Public Class Form1
        Dim degree As Double
        Dim ge As Graphics
        Private Sub Form2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
            ge = e.Graphics
            DrawProgress(ge, New Rectangle(150, 25, 400, 400), degree)
        End Sub

        Private Sub DrawProgress(g As Graphics, rect As Rectangle, degree As Double)
            'work out the angles for each arc
            Dim progressAngle = CSng(degree)
            Dim remainderAngle = 360 - progressAngle

            'create pens to use for the arcs
            Using progressPen As New Pen(Color.LightSeaGreen, 2), remainderPen As New Pen(Color.LightGray, 2)
                'set the smoothing to high quality for better output
                g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
                'draw the blue and white arcs
                g.DrawArc(progressPen, rect, -90, progressAngle)
                g.DrawArc(remainderPen, rect, progressAngle - 90, remainderAngle)
            End Using

            'draw the text in the centre by working out how big it is and adjusting the co-ordinates accordingly
            Using fnt As New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 50)
                Dim text As String = degree.ToString
                Dim textSize = g.MeasureString(text, fnt)
                Dim textPoint As New Point(CInt(rect.Left + (rect.Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2)), CInt(rect.Top + (rect.Height / 2) - (textSize.Height / 2)))
                'now we have all the values draw the text
                g.DrawString(text, fnt, Brushes.Black, textPoint)
            End Using
        End Sub

        Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
            Dim input_s As String
            input_s = TextBox1.Text
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input_s)) Then
                degree = 0
            Else
                degree = CDec(input_s)
            End If
            DrawProgress(ge, New Rectangle(150, 25, 400, 400), degree)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Change DrawProgress() in: `DrawProgress(rect As Rectangle, degree As Double)` then  `Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()` `g.Clear(Me.BackColor)`. Delete/comment out the code in the Paint() event.

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you! Do you mind giving a quick explanation about why it needs to be done like that? I'm guessing that by trying to pass g that it was just giving incorrect information.

Comment: The Graphics object is erased with every WM_PAINT message. I cannot be stored in a variable. You have to create it anew in the context you use it.

Comment: Do not use `CreateGraphics` and do not try to (re)use a global one.  Do all painting in the Paintevent using the graphics object passed to you

Comment: Remember to Dispose() of the Graphics object you created. It's important.